# Can I import a non-abstract type abstractly?

Tags: haskell, module, abstract-data-type

Suppose I have a module that contains a type:

```
module My where

data L a = Nil | Cons a (L a)
```

The module exports the concrete definition of `My` to allow for pattern matching etc. 
Is it possible for another module, say `Client` to import `My` in a manner where `L a` 
is abstract i.e. such that pattern matching on `L a` values is prohibited by the type-checker?

Answer (score 6):

Yes; you just have to use the import list:

```
module Client where

import My (L)
ok :: L Int
ok = undefined

bad :: L Int
bad = Cons 3 Nil

bad2 :: L Int -> Int
bad2 (Cons i _) = i
bad2 Nil        = 0
```

If you try to compile this, you'll get the following four errors:

```
Client.hs:8:10: Not in scope: data constructor `Cons'
Client.hs:8:17: Not in scope: data constructor `Nil'
Client.hs:11:10: Not in scope: data constructor `Cons'
Client.hs:12:9: Not in scope: data constructor `Nil'
```

If you did want to import the constructors, you would instead specify `L(..)`, or `L(Cons)` to import `Cons` but not `Nil`.

For some other ways you can use the `import` statement, check out [the HaskellWiki article on `import`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Import) (although the article doesn't mention importing data types and their constructors).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you may do

```
import My(L())
```

to import a type without importing any of its constructors. If you still wish to construct values of this type (but not pattern match), you must import functions for doing that construction (for example, by exporting such functions from `My` or by creating a utility module with such functions).

edit: Since you explicitly mentioned that you wanted a *type-checking* error, I should point out for completeness that this won't cause pattern-matching on `Nil` and `Cons` to be a type-checking error, but merely a scoping error.

Comment: Note that this is pretty much exactly the same syntax used to *export* a type without its constructors, and also that just `import My(L)` does the same thing.

Comment: ...also, I mention the second form because for *some reason* I keep getting it in my head that `import M(T)` should be equivalent to `import M(T(..))`, not `import M(T())`, a notion which GHC disabuses me of rather forcefully.